# hadoop map-reduce job crashes with initialization failed: java.io.IOException: Split metadata size exceeded 10000000. Aborting job

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, split, mapreduce, metadata

I am also getting the error "Split metadata size exceeded 10000000" the issue on CDH3 -Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u1. In my case the there were two inputs
inp1 size = 1GB
inp2 size = 7 MB

When I am using mapred.max.split.size = 256MB, it throws the below error.

```
Job initialization failed: java.io.IOException: Split metadata size exceeded 10000000. Aborting job job_201412112225_1046114 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.SplitMetaInfoReader.readSplitMetaInfo(SplitMetaInfoReader.java:48) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.createSplits(JobInProgress.java:814) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.initTasks(JobInProgress.java:708) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.initJob(JobTracker.java:4016) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.EagerTaskInitializationListener$InitJob.run(EagerTaskInitializationListener.java:79) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

When I change the mapred.max.split.size = 8MB, then it runs successfully BUT takes too many mappers.

The same job with same configurations is running fine on cdh4.6

Any hints/suggestions to fix this.

Comment: These link will help you ,http://blog.dongjinleekr.com/my-hadoop-job-crashes-with-split-metadata-size-exceeded/ or http://garrens.com/blog/2014/12/08/split-metadata-size-exceeded-10000000/

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: Both the articles talk about modifying mapreduce.jobtracker.split.metainfo.maxsize=-1. I do not want to change this property as this may cause unintended consequences if cluster do not have the resources to handle the actual job.

Comment: You can pass this configuration through command line also. Command should be `-D mapreduce.jobtracker.split.metainfo.maxsize=-1` or you can set this configuration in your MapReduce code too.

Comment: Passing configuration through command line or setting property in MapReduce program will be job specific.

Answer (score 1):

For cloudera, setting "mapreduce.jobtracker.split.metainfo.maxsize" to -1 should do the job. 
Alternatively, you may need to set "mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize" to -1, per https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml.